# Lock pattern for mobile screen with android studio

Tags: android

Can any one help me please l want to make apps that lock mobile home screen by lock pattern ,l made the lock pattern code but l can not relate with the mobile home screen .....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code @DO Nia

Comment: I made like this https://github.com/pro100svitlo/LockPattern?files=1

Comment: But not apply on mobile home screen can help me please to apply